# HTC desire android 2.2 (version prob after factory reset)

Tags: android

I purchased a HTC desire month ago and upon first usage it asked me to update to newer system version (which was to 2.3) i think.

Today i have formatted my sd card + reset to factory settings (from settings).

AFTER the reset of the device now when i go to settings > about phone
it shows me that i am running android 2.2 version.

secondly when i go to settings > about phone > system updates > check now

it says there are no updates available.

does this means i cannot move to android 2.3 now or what?

any help would be appreciated.

btw, my device aint rooted.

Android Version: 2.2
Kernel Version: 2.6.32.15-g2633d94

Build Number: 2.33.161.2 CL284385 release-keys

Software Number: 2.33.161.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 2.3 is not rolled out yet. I have no HTC Desire, but maybe another owner of this handy can write the latest build number here.

Anyway the recent version out in the world is 2.2.1 (as far as I know). I am not sure if HTC delivered this update to the Desire devices or if the 2.2 is the recent for them.

Answer (score 0):

Android 2.3 is only available for Nexus S right now. When this update is available for your handset you will be notified with an OTA update notification.

You can get more information here:
http://www.htc.com/sea/support.aspx